# Mod Rewrite PHP and send values to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I use this `.htaccess` code for rewrite URLs :**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /test_2/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^register test_rewrite.php?action=reg&send=ik&mode=insert [L,NC]
```

My idea is different rules for different files in PHP, for example for `search.php`, `blog.php`, `users.php`, and in each case use specific rules.

Also in each URL for same file, for example `users.php`, I send different parameters, in some moments use strings as action, mode, or simple action for send values in the URLs, as the most traditional use when create PHP scripts without URL friendly.

The case it´s I need send different values and detect these values inside `.htaccess` for rewrite, the most automatic possible.

I want can put unlimited slash for the same URL, for example `search/test/test1/test1`, without get error 404, actually this works if I only use prefix, but need detect value send from PHP URL

My idea is create rule detect the value I send from for example the URL I put as example

```
RewriteRule ^register test_rewrite.php?action=reg&send=ik&mode=insert
```

The idea is `^register` receive all values for get as `$_GET`, as in the example I put until

**For example :**

If my URL is `insert.php?action=reg&send=ik&id=123` and id is different in each case, and I want send to `.htaccess` as `URL/test_2/register/123`, how I can make this?

And finally, really I want get can put URL with different amount of slashes and can show as friendly without receive 404 error and send the values.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, but I would like to give it a shot.

If I understand this right then you are looking for a way to have a rule capture a single (here numeric) argument, while at the same time you want to ignore any prefixed path up to a certain keyword you want to match in the rule.

This might put you onto the right track:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?:^|.*/)register(?:/(\d+))$ insert.php?action=reg&send=ik&id=$1 [END]
```

This will rewrite all these requests to the same target:

> `https://example.com/register/111` => `/insert.php?action=reg&send=ik&id=111`
>
> `https://example.com/foo/register/222` => `/insert.php?action=reg&send=ik&id=222`
>
> `https://example.com/foo/bar/register/333` => `/insert.php?action=reg&send=ik&id=333`

You certainly need to modify this, adapt it to your specific needs. So nothing you can blindly copy.

Comment: No works for me i try this and work me RewriteRule ^register/([^/]+)$ test_rewrite.php?action=register&mode=insert&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L] , the only problem is i need put exactly this url and if put another slash give error, for example URL/register/value works but if put the same and add other slash as for example /tester1, give error

Comment: Sorry, but again your explanation is vague, unclear. This way it is impossible to precisely answer, since it is unclear what you actually ask. You'd have to revise your question, give _clear_ and _precise_ examples for all the situations and the expected behavior. Above code works, if it does not do what you expect then you need to explain what you actually expect.